# Writing to http.ResponseWriter after defining multipart writer

Tags: go, stream, multipart

I'm defining a multipart writer to stream data directly to a response writer of type `http.ResponseWriter`. In case of errors and for the simplicity of the example, I write the status code to w as follows:

```
if err != nil {
    w.WriteHeader(404) // works as expected, 404 is written
    fmt.Println(w) // status code is 404
    return
}

multiPartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(w)
defer multiPartWriter.Close()

if err != nil {
    w.WriteHeader(404) // weirdly gets ignored
    fmt.Println(w) // status code is 200
    return
}
```

As the example shows, any error that occurs before defining the multipart writer works as expected, any error that occurs after gets ignored. I know for sure that `w.WriteHeader(404)` gets executed, it just weirdly gets ignored, no error is returned. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: You can't write headers multiple times, only once. If you reach an error, send back an error response and **return**. Also note that if you've written anything to the output (e.g. `w.Write()`), that implies sending a 200 status if it wasn't set explicitly.

Comment: I'm not trying to write headers multiple times, these are different cases, I updated the example. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't write anything to `w` before setting the status, as noted above, writing to it implies sending 200 status. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: oh, so writing things to w then writing the status code would imply that the status code would be ignored? that is kind of a pain :( I'm trying to stream data directly and maybe something would break in the middle

Comment: Writing anything to the output must preceded by writing status code. This is in the HTTP spec. If later you "change your mind", you can't take the status code back and send another status.

Comment: to be frank that is a minimal reproducible example. in order to understand things, I'm trying to write the status code directly before and after defining the multipart stream. Thanks for the feedback and for taking the time to look into this. Please let me know if it's still confusing!

Comment: So apparently, the first write to will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) (thank you so much @icza!). The thing is that I'm not sure how to report errors in this case? also I'm not calling w.Write at all, I'm just defining the new multipart stream.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally know what is going on (thanks to @icza for the leads). Any write to w triggers an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK), and overwriting the header after that is not possible. This is why the explicit set of the status code gets ignored. It's weird that golang doesn't produce any warning about it though.

Comment: The `net/http` package does warn you about this, it will log a line to stderr with `http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from ...` showing exactly where you incorrectly called `w.WriteHeader`